# Ordenar arreglo de menor a mayor

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {     
    int [] a  = {7,2,4,8,3,9,1,5,10,6};
    int menor;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        menor = a[0];

        if (a[i] < menor){
            menor = a[i];
        }
        else{
            if (a[i] > menor){
              menor = menor;
            }      
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: Solo `Arrays.sort(a);`

Comment: Aileen, porque no usas el metodo sort(), como indica Joel? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se llama orden burbuja.

```
int a[] = {5,3,2,7,10,1};
    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length-x-1; i++) {
            if(a[i] < a[i+1]){
                int tmp = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = a[i];
                a[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

La forma más sencilla y adecuada es usando el método [**sort()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-char:A-) :

```
  int [] a  = {7,2,4,8,3,9,1,5,10,6};
  Arrays.sort(a);
```

Para comprobarlo, imprime el contenido del array:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

y obtendrás como salida el `array` ordenado de menor a mayor (ascendente):

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

Te recomiendo este excelente artículo donde muestra otras formas de ordenar un `array` en Java.

[**Formas de ordenar un array en java.**](https://www.discoduroderoer.es/formas-de-ordenar-un-array-en-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método de [ordenamiento de burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) (Bubble sort). Este método revisa y arregla el orden de cada elemento del arreglo comparándolo con el siguiente. El proceso se repite varias veces hasta que se hayan verificado todos los elementos, ya no sean necesarios más cambios y el arreglo se encuentre ordenado.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a  = {7,2,4,8,3,9,1,5,10,6};
    int temporal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (a.length - i); j++) {
            if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                temporal = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temporal;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

He cambiado el número `10` por `a.length`. De esta manera el algoritmo será más flexible, funcionando para cualquier arreglo sin importar la cantidad de elementos que contenga.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando la respuesta de **@spuente**, burbuja se puede optimizar fácilmente, reduciendo su tiempo de ejecución en un 50% en el peor caso detectando cuando el array se encuentra ordenado en alguna de las iteraciones, evitando una buena cantidad de comparaciones.

En cada iteración se asume que el array esta ordenado, seteando un flag `sorted = true`, luego, en el loop donde se intercambian los elementos desordenados, si se encuentran dos elementos desordenados se setea `sorted = false`

En cada iteración se chequea si `sorted` se mantiene `true`, de ser así implica que se iteró sobre los `list.length -i -1` elementos restantes sin encontrar elementos desordenados y por ende el array se encuentra ordenado y no tiene sentido seguir iterando sobre el mismo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        optimizedBubbleSort(new int[]{1,2,4,5,6}); // Iteración 0, array ordenado
        optimizedBubbleSort(new int[]{11,2,44,5,16}); // Iteración 2, array ordenado
        optimizedBubbleSort(new int[]{0,8,74,5,1}); // Iteración 3, array ordenado
}

    private static void optimizedBubbleSort(int [] list){
        for(int i =0; i< list.length; i++){
            boolean sorted = true; // asumo que para la iteración i el listado es ordenado,
            for(int j =0; j< list.length - i - 1; j++){ // en cada iteración los elementos desde la posición (length-i) estan ordenados, por lo tanto solo recorro hasta esa posición
                if(list[j] > list[j+1]){
                    int temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j+1];
                    list[j+1] = temp;
                    sorted = false; 
                }
            }
            if(sorted){ 
                System.out.println(String.format("Iteración %s, array ordenado", i));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Integer[] num  = {2,3,1,5,7,8,11};
       Arrays.asList(num).stream()
               .sorted((x,y)-> y.compareTo(x))
               .map(x -> {
                   Integer contador = 0;
                   for (int i = 1; i <= num.length; i++) {
                        if(x%i == 0){
                            contador ++;
                        }
                   }
                   if(contador == 2){
                       return x;
                   }
                   return 0;
               }).filter(numPrimo -> numPrimo>0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ordena y filtra solo números primos:

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].