# Cuando un usuario tiene almacenados 10 números en un array, ¿cómo hacer que los muestre de menor a mayor los números ingresados?

Tags: java, array, netbeans

```
package pkg10alreves;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int locker [];
    locker = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Ingrese 10 números");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        locker[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(locker[i] <= 1){
            System.out.println(locker[i]);
        }
        else if(locker[i] <= 2) {
            System.out.println(locker[i]);
        }
        else if(locker[i] <= 3) {
            System.out.println(locker[i]);
        }
        //Estoy perdido :´C
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Aqui lo respondieron [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106335/ordenar-arreglo-de-menor-a-mayor]

Answer (score 1):

Se puede utilizar `sort` de Array.

```
Arrays.sort(locker);
```

[Java.util.Arrays.sort(int[])](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm)

Comment: Probablemente Emiliano está estudiando algoritmos de ordenación y si bien, eso resuelve el problema, quizas le convenga mirar esto https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordenamiento y partir por el más sencillo: el ordenamiento burbuja https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja

Answer (score 0):

No se mucho de programación, pero si lo tuviera que hacer:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int locker [];
        int aux=0;
        locker = new int[10];

        System.out.println("Ingrese 10 números");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            locker[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            aux = locker[i];
            for (int j = i-1; j>=0 && locker[j]>aux;j--){
                locker[j+1]=locker[j];
                locker[j]= aux;
            }   
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println(locker[i]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java tiene muchas funcionalidades en el SDK. Una clase muy importante al trabajar con arrays es "Arrays". En ella te encontrarás con métodos para ordenarlos. Simplemente con Arrays.sort(locker) ya te ordena el array de menor a mayor (en caso de mayor a menor harías después un Arrays.reverse).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int locker[];
    locker = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Ingrese 10 números");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        locker[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(locker);
    for(int num : locker){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```